# Obfuscate a String of date pattern

Tags: java, regex, date, replace

I have String's for Date pattern like `mm/dd/yyyy` , `mm-dd-yyyy`, `mm.dd.yyyy` etc.

I want to obfuscate it like this `##/##/####`, `##-##-####`, `##.##.####`

One idea could be to use `replaceAll` for 'm', 'd', 'y' . But is there any other cleaner solution?

Comment: Does the string contain anything else other than the timestamp?

Comment: `dt = dt.replaceAll("[mdy]", "#");` should be clean enough

Comment: I hope you mean `mm/DD/yyyy`, `mm-DD-yyyy` and `mm.DD.yyyy`.

Comment: @Kayaman Are you sure about `d->D` and not `m->M`?

Comment: @Pshemo My european brain only remembers that "the middle characters are uppercase" ;) Indeed, the months are supposed to be uppercase.

Comment: @Kayaman I thought that is the case since mine does the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to that.

A very simple thing: **after** you created normally formatted date strings (like 2016-09-08); to take that date and replace any **digit** with #.

Of course, that has one big advantage: you do a lot of processing; just to throw all of the computed output away in the end.

So, you better rework your formats, like:

```
obscuredFormat = regularFormat.replaceAll("[mMdy]", "#");
```

Comment: Just to be sure, if i have pattern Mm-yyyy-DD , i can just use (?i)[mdy] ?

Comment: Oh ok, i see, so no direct way to use case insensitive operation here other than specifying all the characters.

Comment: replaceAll takes a **regex**, and those have "special" rules.